# Blogger automatically includes href tag when switch between 'html' and 'compose' mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, blogspot

I am facing two issues, bother are pretty much similar.
When I add this code to a blogger/blogspot page it works fine, but as soon as I switch to 'compose' mode from 'html' and save the post it changes the  tag automatically and gives error link.

1. I am adding below code to blogger page where I want to show hide content, this doesn't work if I switch to 'compose' mode

```css
.cattext input {
display: none;
margin: 0 10% 0 0;
}

.catlink {
float:right;
margin: 0 10% 0 0;

}

input {
display: none;
}

.cattitle {
  padding: 10px 10px; */
    margin: 1em;
    /* background: #333; */
    color: #ffce00;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
cursor: default;
margin: 0 0 0 5%;
}

.cattext .text {
    display:none;
    margin-top:1em;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
margin: 0 0 0 5%;
}

.cattext input#button:checked ~ .text {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cattext">
  <label for="button">
    <a class="cattitle" role="button">Cool Keychains</a>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="button">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eum delenit constituto in. Mea ut senserit voluptatum efficiantur, an usu vidit augue consequat. Mei iusto everti ocurreret no. Eum ut vidisse facilisis definitiones. Per melius honestatis ei, justo illum dicat sit eu, ex sit vidit ponderum. Ei quod ludus deseruisse vis, eu nihil percipit inciderint his.</div>
</div>
```

2. The 'next' 'previous' slider buttons also stops working (adds a href tag automatically) when I switch to 'compose' and save post, below is the code and the slider script.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none;
opacity: 1;
}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}


/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Blogger editor automatically adds href attribute to `<a>` elements without href, so you can use another element like `<span>` instead of `<a>` or if you want to use `<a>` anyway, add href like this `href='javascript:void(0)'`

Comment: Yes, I am adding the code inside the style and script tags, but blogger modifies the <a> tag 

For example: this tag <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>   will automatically become  <a class="prev" href="https://www.blogger.com/null" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>

This is happening when I switch to compose mode and save the post. You please check this at your end.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! <span> tag works perfectly. Also the button tag works. Great help, thanks a lot! Bassam and Bram

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a great way to see that you should be using `button`s (type=button). I am convinced that many frameworks use `a` too often where `button` should be used. You want to do an action on the page that does not change navigation for the user, use button.

If you want to stick with `a`, you can do something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[href$='/null']").forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```